# CodeBehind class not accessible to code in App_Code folder

Tags: asp.net

I have a PlannerShiftView user control in the root folder of my ASP.NET web ***site***.  In my App_Code folder, I have a ShiftViewTemplate class that needs to instantiate a PlannerShiftView (for a TemplateField in a GridView).  The problem is, the following code doesn't compile because the PlannerShiftView type is not available in what I deem to be the App_Code 'phantom namespace'.

Please can somebody explain to be what is happening here, as well as what to do.  I know I can just move the ShiftViewTemplate out of App_Code, going against convention and without explantion, but that is something of a hollow victory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.Net websites do not compile into a single assembly, but into several ones. Therefore the code of your user control in not referenceable by the App_Code assembly.

The way I solved a similar case:

- declare an IPlannerShiftView interface in App_Code or an external assembly
- declare the PlannerShiftView control as implementing the IPlannerShiftView interface
- instantiate the control using Page.LoadControl, and cast to interface

Comment: Good idea, but a bit of work.  Pity we have to do this.  For now, I'm just taking the ShiftViewTemplate out of App_Code.  It is UI code after all.